# Animate icons change

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am working on my first application, its a mathematical riddles app. The player can get a hint that will reveal one of the variables - it's basically replacing one image with another. Sometimes I am replacing more than one image so I am using a loop that replace all of them. I want the old image to fade and be replaced with the new image, the answer. Also I would like them to fade one after the other, meaning that there will be a small delay between one image replacement animation to the next.

```
func changeHintIcons () {

    var labelsArr = [[firstEquationFirstElemnt,firstEquationSecondElemnt,firstEquationThirdElemnt],[secondEquationFirstElemnt,secondEquationSecondElemnt,secondEquationThirdElemnt],[thirdEquationFirstElemnt,thirdEquationSecondElemnt,thirdEquationthirdElemnt],[fourthEquationFirstElemnt,fourthEquationSecondElemnt,fourthEquationThirdElemnt],        [fifthEquationFirstElemnt,fifthEquationSecondElemnt,fifthEquationThirdElemnt]]

    let col:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(gameDifficulty.stages[gameLevel].umberOfVariables)))

    let row:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(2))) * 2

    let var_to_show = current_equations[col][row]
    let image_name = "answer.num.\(var_to_show)"
    for i in 0..<current_equations.count {
        for j in 0..<current_equations[i].count {
            if (current_equations[i][j] == var_to_show) {
                var image_index = j
                if (j > 0) { 
                    image_index = Int(j/2)   //Converting index
                }
                labelsArr[i][image_index]!.image = UIImage(named: image_name)!  //Replacing the image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One last thing, what if I want to use in an animation instead of letting the image simply fade out? What are my options and how can I implement them?

Comment: Is labelsArr[i][image_index] a UIImageView

Comment: Yes it's a UIImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer. Basically swift allows you to create your animation by projecting a set of images one after the other. Follow these steps:
1. Copy animation images to assets folder
2. create an array of UIImages
3. Do the same things as I did in the animate function

Main code -

```
var animationArray = createImageArray(total: 14, imagePrefix: "hint.animation")
animationArray.append(UIImage(named: imageHintAnswer)!)
animate(imageView: labelsArr[i][image_index]!, images: animationArray)
```

Functions -

```
func createImageArray(total: Int, imagePrefix: String) -> [UIImage] {
    var imageArray:[UIImage] = []
    for imageCount in 1..<total {
        let imageName = "\(imagePrefix).\(imageCount)"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)!

        imageArray.append(image)
    }

    return imageArray
}

func animate(imageView: UIImageView, images: [UIImage]) {
    imageView.animationImages = images
    imageView.animationDuration = 0.7
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    imageView.startAnimating()
}
```